# Intel WiDi Issues with Smart TV and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I (very) recently got a brand-new TCL Roku Smart TV (Model Number: `48FS3750`). So far, it's been a lot of fun. There are tons of features, and the image is great compared to what I had. Since I like to play around with tech, I went into the settings and found the option to enable screen mirroring.

I enabled mirroring and looked up how to use it. After going through countless tutorials showing how I could use Windows 8.1/10's built in feature to mirror my screen to the TV, and countless guides saying it's possible on Windows 7 but not worth it, I finally found out what to do; I had to install the Intel WiDi Utility.

Now, I read in most of the guides that most laptops that came with Windows 7 wouldn't work, but I wasn't all that worried, since my laptop came with Windows 8.1. Right now, I currently have a triple-boot setup with Windows 7, 10 and Ubuntu. I installed the WiDi utility and had a ton of trouble, but eventually got it to the point I am at now.

I open the app and it finds my TV, so I click it. It connects fine: the TV says it's showing video from the laptop; the programs says it's connected and gives me an option between mirroring my display or extending it.

Here's the problem: **the TV is blank**.

It's still responsive, and I can exit out, but no matter what I do I can't get it to display my laptop's screen, or simulate a second, wireless display. It just stays blank.

Looking around online, I found some posts and such that suggested having a custom theme might be a problem. I figured that might be the problem, so I switched to the default Windows 7 theme. Nothing.

Another source suggested that maybe the screen resolution was wrong. Seeing as my laptop (`MSi GP60 2QF`) has a 1080p screen, and the TV is also 1080p, I didn't think this was a problem; but I tried it anyway, with no result. Just a blank screen.

I have run the WiDi Update Tool, and it says everything is good: my hardware is compatible, and there are no necessary updates.

I have tested with my Android phone, and the screencast works perfectly fine with it. It is only my computer causing the problem.

I do have Windows 10, like I said, but I can't stand it, especially after my last installation slowly broke down over time, forcing me to go through a reinstall nightmare. I really would like to not use it, and get Windows 7 working, if at all possible.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I do have switchable graphics (NVIDIA GTX 950m X Intel HD 4600), and I did read something that said NVIDIA doesn't work with Miracast and WiDi; but I'm not currently using the card. I really hope this isn't the issue.

Any help is appreciated. If you need more details than the history of what I've done, ask, and I'll do my best.

***EDIT:***

Windows 10 works fine. It had an older version of the WiFi driver installed, but the newest one still works fine.

Comment: You don't say if it works on the Windows 10 installation or not

Comment: @Ramhound I'll go test it. My common sense isn't currently present :p

Comment: @Ramhound 10 works, but it has an old WiFi card version: 18.21.0.2. The latest, which 7 has, is 18.33.0.2. I'm going to update it and see if it still works.

Comment: Nope. Still works with the newest driver.

Comment: Here is the thing, I honestly thought this feature, never was on Windows 7 devices ever, I only saw it after Windows 8 was released.

Comment: @Ramhound Well this is a Windows 8 device, and it is hardware compatible. The software says it works with Windows 7, and it does for the most part. I just can't get an image.